# Manipulate dom based on child directives attribute - angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here goes my html code.

```
<parent>
    <div idx=2>DIV - 3</div>
    <div idx=0>DIV - 1</div>
    <div idx=1>DIV - 2</div>
</parent>
```

I need to reorder the child divs based on directives attribute. so here goes my angularjs code. Based on `idx` value i want to manipulate the DOM.

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});
app.directive('idx', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.idx);
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            idx: '='
        },
        link: link
    }
});
```

I am new to angularjs. please help me or just provide some hint to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda very difficult. I have this suggestion to achieve this. Create `$scope` array variable(with sorting by `idx`) and bind all the childs using `ng-repeat`. Try the following code. It should work as you expected.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.indexes = [
    {key: 2, value: 3},
    {key: 0, value: 1},
    {key: 1, value: 2}
  ];
  
  $scope.indexes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.key > b.key;
  });
}]);

app.directive("parent", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E"
    }
});

app.directive("idx", function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.idx);
    }
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            idx: "="
        },
        link: link
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <parent>
    <div ng-repeat="index in indexes" idx="index.key">
      DIV - {{index.value}}
    </div>
  </parent>
</div>
```